# How to create a filter with bcc or cc

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

When I create a filter in gmail I can enter values for the `from` and `to` field like this:

[image]

However, I can't add any value for `cc` or `bcc`.

I need to create a filter where `bcc` is from `example@mail.com` .

I can use the following in the gmail search

```
bcc:example@mail.com
```

but can I generate a filter that matches all the mails from that search?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can.

You will need to add your email address on the `Includes the words` field

**Includes the words `cc:example@mail.com`**

You can even include **both `bcc` and `cc`** in just one filter:

```
(bcc:example@mail.com OR cc:example@mail.com)
```

*(Since you mention "I can use the following in the gmail search `bcc:example@mail.com` but can I generate a filter that matches all the mails from that search?", I assume you talk about emails you sent. Because as mentioned in [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190/),you can't find messages that **you received** on bcc)*

[image: Create a bcc or cc filter in gmail]

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.